# Subtracting the value from the set attribute

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to vertical center one element in div:

[image]

While i set element top 50%, the element is not centered because the height of the element is also involved:

```
<i class="fas fa-angle-right" class="icon"></i>

<style>
.icon{
font-size: 1.2rem;
margin-top:50%;
}
</style>
```

[image]

Is there any way to calculate the top margin like this?

```
.icon{
font-size: 1.2rem;
margin-top:calc(50% - font-size/2);
}
```

Comment: No, you can not use `font-size` like that in the calculation - but you can use a value in an em or rem unit, something like `calc(50% - 1.2em / 2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for.

I guess you are looking forward to absolute position the arrow icon vertically to the center of its container. Let me know if this helps.

```
 .parentWrapper {
   position: relative;
 }

 .icon {
   position: absolute;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
   top: 50%;
   right: 0; // in case you need it to be aligned right
  }
```